# Can I write custom kafka connect transform for converting JSON to AVRO?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use kafka-connect-hdfs for writing schemaless json records from kafka to hdfs file.
If I am using JsonConvertor as key/value convertor then it is not working. But if I am using StringConvertor then it writes the json as escaped string.

For example:

actual json -

```
{"name":"test"}
```

data written to hdfs file -

```
"{\"name\":\"test\"}"
```

expected output to hdfs file -

```
{"name":"test"}
```

Is there any way or alternative I can achieve this or I have to use it with schema only?

Below is the exception I get when I try to use JSONConvertor:

```
[2017-09-06 14:40:19,344] ERROR Task hdfs-sink-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:148)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:308)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:406)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Configuration of **quickstart-hdfs.properties**:

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test_hdfs_avro
hdfs.url=hdfs://localhost:9000
flush.size=1
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

Configuration of **connect-avro-standalone.properties**:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
schemas.enable=false
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Comment: "If I am using JsonConvertor as key/value convertor then it is not working." -> can you describe the issue you're seeing? the error you get?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have added the exception and properties I have configured for this connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a converter in you connector's configuration properties you need to include all the properties pertaining to this converter, regardless of whether such properties are included in the worker's config too.

In the above example, you'll need to specify both:

```
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

in *quickstart-hdfs.properties*.

FYI, JSON export is coming up in the HDFS Connector soon. Track the related pull request here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/196

*Update*: JsonFormat has been merged to master branch.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please update this thread when request is merged to master and available for use?

Comment: JsonFormat has been merged.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So to use this code. Will I have to download master and build this manually or is there some other way?

Comment: That is correct. It will be included in the forthcoming release of Confluent platform. Early adopters will need to build from source until then.

Comment: Ok Thanks but is there a manual where I can find what all projects do I need to build and steps to build source manually?
 I tried building common and hdfs but hdfs project showed other dependencies error. It was not able to find dependencies on confluent maven repository. Any idea?

Comment: Usually this info is in the FAQ section of the Connector's github page. E.g. for the HDFS Connector: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/wiki/FAQ (needs to be updated to include kafka-connect-storage-common) and for kafka-connect-storage-common: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Downvoted because this will result in each entry in the output being a simple string, which is not noted anywhere.